# Allow installation of apps from unknown sources inside work profile in Android Marshmallow

Tags: wso2, android-for-work, wso2-iot

I've managed to set WSO2 EMM 2.2.0 server and have tested out the emm android agent which works. However, for "Android for work", when I tried to push enterprise applications, it says that "Your administrator doesn't allow installation of apps obtained from unknown sources".

Is there a way to install the apps in the work profile from unknown sources?

Answer (score 2):

The intention of work-profile is to have a safe container for work-related data. Therefore Android is not allowing to install apps from unknown sources in work-profile what so ever. What is only possible is enabling playstore in the work-profile and downloading apps from there.
The only work-around that you can do to install apps from unknown source is by [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html).

Configure the work profile first and then using ADB push an app to the device. The app will be installed in both work-profile and personal profile.
At the moment that is the only work-around possible.

Android for Work is still not saturated. There are grey areas to be addressed. I believe Android will come up with options for this scenario soon.